# Eloquent retornando campo e valor

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Meu select está retornando o campo e o valor do id que está na tabela e preciso que retorne apenas o valor,como fazer?

```
$id = DB::table('participantes')
        ->select('id')
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')
        ->take(1)
        ->get();
```

Erro retornado

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":173}]' for column 'participante_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `participantes` (`opcao_id`, `questao_id`, `participante_id`) values (291, 84, [{"id":173}]))

Comment: Sabe que `get` é diferente de `first` né?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou pegar apenas o `id` do resultado ao invés de usar o array?

```
$result = DB::table('participantes')
        ->select('id')
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')
        ->first();

$id = $result->id;
```

Comment: Fernando,está retornando Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. com o código da forma que me mandou.

Comment: Falha minha, editado...

Comment: Funcionou,obrigado.